# Error Access-Control-Allow-Origin With Angular.js and API with Laravel5.1

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5.1

i am developing an application with Laravel 5.1 and Angular.js and when i try to connect i have the next error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/university. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have the next code in angular:

```
angular.module('clientApp')

.controller('UniversityCtrl', function ($scope, $resource) {
  Universities = $resource("http://localhost:8000/university/:id",{id: "@id"});

  $scope.Universities = Universities.query();
});
```

My view:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>University</th>
     <th>Address</th>
     <th>Phone</th>
   </tr>
</thead>

 <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="Universities in University">
      <td>{{University.name}}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

and my code of Laravel:

```
    public function index()
{
    $universities = university::all();
    return response()->json(
        $universities->toArray()
    );
}
```

Thanks :D

Comment: use same port for both front end and back end or implement CORS. Different ports = cross domain. Easy to google that error for full details

Comment: How can implement CORS?

Comment: by researching it.... question gets asked daily here and there are lots of resources in a google search to explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single Install this [package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) by barryvdh